# Objective-C Not to override methods declared in implementation

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

I have a class that inherits from `UIViewController`. This class provides the basic features that several view controllers need to implement so they will inherit from this class. Reason why I'm not using it to directly create any instances.

Both the parent and the child class have a method called `setupView` that is called in each class' `viewDidLoad`. Both classes have exactly the same method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self setupView];
}
```

`setupView` is not declared in the `interface`, it's just defined in the `implementation`, which I though will prevent any other class to have access to it or to override it. However, when the parent's `viewDidLoad` is called by its child and `[self setupView]` is executed, the child's `setupView` is called instead of its own.

I have two question:

1. Why can I child class override a method that it's not declared in the interface?
2. How can I prevent this?

**--Edit--**

Each `setupView` method perform configurations that are exclusive to that view controller. For example the parent uses this method to configure `UIBarButtonItem` that every child class needs, and the child uses it to configure the table view it will use.

I don't want to configure the `UIBarButtonItem` in the child class because then I will have to do it in every child, and that's exactly why I decided to create the parent class. I also don't want to use `[super setupView]` because the child is not supposed to know anything about this method in the parent class.

Being able to override a method that is not declared in the interface isn't against encapsulation principles?

**--Answer--**

Any method in Objective-C can be overridden, including those that are not declared in the `interface`. This means the methods in the child classes must have different names, unless the intention is to override the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a child implements the same method as a parent, it basically overwrites this method. You can then call the parent method with `[super methodName]`. So if you're overwriting `setupView` in the child and also want to have the parent's `setupView` be called, you should call it from the child:

```
- (void)setupView
{
    [super setupView];
    // child code
}
```

Comment: Also, you should remove additional [self setupView] call from the viewDidLoad in child. Leave that work to the parent ;)

Comment: Please check the edit.
I don't want to call `[super setupView]` because the child is not supposed to know this method exists. I thought one is jut able to override or called methods declared only in the interface. Wouldn't it be unsafe if I use a framework and override a private method by mistake? There's no way I can know if that method actually exists because it's not declared in the interface. Or, is it? Doesn't this go agains encapsulation principles?

Comment: In that case you should use a different name, setupBarButtons or something like that. Because overriding a method will override it for good on that class.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I didn't know it was possible to override non-public methods.

Answer (score 1):

It is the default approach. Child overrides the parent's method.

I see two possible solutions:

- Use different names
- Change child's method as follows:

.

```
- (void)setupView
{
    if([super respondsToSelector:_cmd])
        [super performSelector:_cmd];
    // child code
}
```

Comment: I thought only methods declared in the `interface` can be overridden. Being able to do this doesn't go against encapsulation principles?

Comment: No. All methods. This is a polymorphism in Objective C

Comment: Isn't this unsafe? For example if I'm using a library there's no way I can know which methods are being used in the `implementation`, I know only the methods declared in the `interface`. This means there's a possibility I can override a method I don't even know it exists?

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is check if the class is a sublcass or not and then execute your setupview. But its a bad thing to have to do this. because your subclass should herit everything from its parents